# Laravel rating while creating testimonial

Tags: php, laravel

I am using [this package](https://github.com/willvincent/laravel-rateable) to get rates from users, which works for products/posts completely fine for me but i have an issue when i don't have exist record in my database!

## What I mean?

Normally when you want to rate you will rate to exist record in database such as exist post or exist product and you express yourself about that record by giving start/rates. now i want to use this system for something that doesn't exist such as `testimonial` means: people write their testimonial and give star then save it, here i get error of

> constraint violation: 1048 Column 'rateable_id' cannot be null

and that's simply because this package tries to get id of testimonial while it doesn't exist, so i need a solution to save both together.

### my form

```
<form class="poststars" action="{{route('testimonialsStar')}}" id="addStar" method="POST">
                  {{ csrf_field() }}
                  {{Form::label('comment', 'Comment', array('hidden'))}}
                  {{Form::textarea('comment', null, array('class' => 'form-control'))}}

                  <span style="padding-top: 20px !important;vertical-align: -moz-middle-with-baseline;padding-left: 4%;color: #fff;">give rate</span>
                  <input class="star star-5" value="5" id="star-5" type="radio" name="star"/>
                  <label class="star star-5" for="star-5"></label>
                  <input class="star star-4" value="4" id="star-4" type="radio" name="star"/>
                  <label class="star star-4" for="star-4"></label>
                  <input class="star star-3" value="3" id="star-3" type="radio" name="star"/>
                  <label class="star star-3" for="star-3"></label>
                  <input class="star star-2" value="2" id="star-2" type="radio" name="star"/>
                  <label class="star star-2" for="star-2"></label>
                  <input class="star star-1" value="1" id="star-1" type="radio" name="star"/>
                  <label class="star star-1" for="star-1"></label>

                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" name="submit">Send</button>
                </form>
```

### My routes

```
//Testimonial Rating System
Route::post('/ratingtes', 'IndexController@testimonialsStar')->name('testimonialsStar');
Route::get('/writetestimonials', 'IndexController@testimonialsds')->name('testimonialsindex');
```

### My Methods

```
public function testimonialsStar (Request $request, Testimonial $testimonial) {
      $rating = new Rating;
      $rating->user_id = \Auth::id();
      $rating->rating = $request->input('star');
      $rating->comment = $request->input('comment');
      $rating->rateable_id = str_random(40);
      $testimonial->ratings()->save($rating);
      return redirect()->back();
    }


    public function testimonialsds () {
      return view('frontend.testimonials');
    }
```

Thanks.

Comment: Just create the testimonial before...

Comment: I can't its base on user willing! Have you ever give testimonials to any website? I can't create my website is awesome then users give stars to it :) they write their opinions and set stars then send it.

Comment: What I don't understand is how can you rate something that does not exist? This package adds a trait to a model for this rating... you need a record to rate. I am not sure your use case is clear here...

Comment: @serge  that's exactly what I'm saying `and that's simply because this package tries to get id of testimonial while it doesn't exist, so i need a solution to save both together.` question is how to save them both?

Comment: Form looks general. It need to be related to exact testimonial. Your action route has to consist testimonial id for example.